# Max sum from unique digits

Tags: c++, c++11

Here i am finding maximum sum which can be formed by these (user input) numbers but numbers which are used to sum should not have any digit in common.

- We are given `n` numbers.
- We look at all subsets of this numbers,where every digit appears not more than once.
- For this subsets we calculate the sums.
- We are then looking for the maximum of this sums.

eg. input cases numbers n=5

```
0  1   2  3 - > 6  ( no repeated digits here ) 0+1+2+3
3  30  8  1 - > 39 ( here 3  is repeated so choose max from 3 & 30 i.e. 30) 30+8+1
11 21 31 41 - > 41 ( here 1 is repeated to all so max number will print ) 41
11 5  45 88 - > 99 ( here 5 is repeated so choose max from 45 & 5 i.e 45 ) 11+88+45
17 69 78 89 -> 147  (69 + 78) = 147 


int sum(int Ticket[], int n)
{
    int max;
    int abc;
    for (int i = 0; i <= n; i++) {
        for (int k = 0; k <= n; k++) {
            abc = Ticket[i];
            max = Ticket[i] + Ticket[i]
                int len = to_string(abc).length();

            for (int j = 0; j <= len; j++) {
                std::string nstr = std::to_string(abc);
                std::cout << "->" << nstr[j];
            }
        }
    }
return max;
}
int main()
{ 
       // n total number of array or numbers
        int max = sum(Ticket, n);
}
```

question is how check unique digits of each numbers and form maximum sum.

Comment: Hi. A better place to post such questions is [code review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: With input like `12 23 34 45`, looks like a recursive solution make be needed.

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: Note that the four examples in the start of your code block give a different algorithm than the problem statement. check, for example, `17 69 78 89`

Comment: @chux for input  like 12 23 34 45 o/p is 68 ( 45+ 23)

Comment: @L.ScottJohnson  17 69 78 89  -> output is 106 (69 + 78) = 147

Comment: Please pick ONE language and study [ask]

Comment: @mayank yes, I know. The point was that if you follow the algorithm presented in the four examples at the start of the code block, you end up with 89 alone.

Comment: @L.ScottJohnson let me correct. updated again que.

Answer (score 0):

The size of the set of all subsets of digits is 2^10.

Given a number, you can store `table[digits used]=value`.

Given a table with some entries and a number, you can for each entry, determine if you can use this number.  If so, you add `table[old digit and digits from number]=new sum` if there isn't already an entry there with a higher value.  Include the fact that `table[no digits]=0` when doing this.

This will take O(2^n) time for O(n) input as the table entries grow exponentially, but never more than O(n*1024), as the exponential growth of the entries cannot exceed populating the whole table.

Naively, the table can be impelemented as an `std::unordered_map< unsigned char, unsigned int >` using bitmasks.

This is a dynamic programming solution.